# Why is my array not allocated any more inside subroutine?

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran type which has an entry which is a type again. This type has an allocatable integer array:

```
type inner
    integer, allocatable :: dyn_arr(:)
    integer another_var
end type
type outer
    type(inner) entry
    type(inner) another_entry
end type
```

I allocate the array and then call a subroutine. Inside the subroutine I want to access the array.

```
type(outer) main_struct

allocate(main_struct%entry%dyn_arr(100))
call routi(main_struct)
```

My code segfaults. When I run with debugger, before the call everything seems fine, when I enter the subroutine `routi`, the debugger says `dyn_arr` is not allocated. How can that be?

Comment: You haven't shown nearly enough information to get anything else than a wild guess.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that I called routi(a,b) but defined subroutine routi(b,a). I just did not hope for the problem to be so simple because I had been facing (to me odd) problems of the kind Stefano is describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a short program to test this and did not have any problems.  Could you post a short program that shows this failure?

Here is my code that worked fine when compiled using gfortran 4.5:

```
  MODULE temp_module
    TYPE inner
       INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: dyn_arr(:)
       INTEGER another_var
    END TYPE inner
    TYPE outer
       TYPE(inner) entry
       TYPE(inner) another_entry
    END TYPE outer
  CONTAINS

    SUBROUTINE test (input)
      TYPE(outer), INTENT(in) :: input
      WRITE(*,*) input%entry%dyn_arr
    END SUBROUTINE test

  END MODULE temp_module

  PROGRAM XC_VMEC_SIGHTLINE
    USE temp_module
    TYPE(outer) main_struct

    ALLOCATE(main_struct%entry%dyn_arr(10))
    CALL test(main_struct)
  END PROGRAM XC_VMEC_SIGHTLINE
```

Answer (score -6):

I guess that in routi() you have an intent(out), havent't you ?

From [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlf101a.doc/xlflr/derivedtypes.htm)

> An allocated ultimate allocatable component of an actual argument that
>   is associated with an INTENT(OUT) dummy argument is deallocated on
>   procedure entry so that the corresponding component of the dummy
>   argument has an allocation status of not currently allocated.
>
> This ensures that any pointers that point to the previous contents of
>   the allocatable component of the variable become undefined.

Never use intent(out). It's evil.

Comment: @eriktous: the appropriate use of intent(out) is not to use intent(out) on complex types. We wasted man-weeks on this crap.

Comment: The feature and its behaviour are documented clearly. It's perfectly fine (and many would even say recommended) to use it, when applicable. Of course you shouldn't use it when its meaning conflicts with the intended usage of dummy arguments, but that doesn't warrant a blanket "don't use" statement.

Comment: If you want "information" to flow both into and out of the procedure, then intent should be "inout".   If you declare the intent as "out", it means that nothing is going into the procedure and the compiler is allowed to throw away the existing content and status of the argument.  The argument only has meaning inside and on exit from the procedure.   It makes sense.

Comment: @M.S.B.: I never said it does not make sense. I said that it's dangerous, because it's quite likely that you step onto these subtleties. Also, I consider quite stupid to downvote me, since I could be right (the question does not allow to discriminate).

Comment: @eriktous : there are plenty of well documented behaviors in javascript as well, yet someone considered useful to write a book "Javascript: The good parts". Intent out remains a potential source of trouble, and considering the history of fortran to generate troubles out of undefined behavior that then magically turn into standard (that make even more mess), I still hold my point, and I still claim that he periodically makes us waste time, and we are all developers with tens of years of experience.

Comment: about the array getting deallocated if intent(out) is specified: with static arrays I always thought it would be correct Fortran style to deal with functions that want to return an array by declaring the array outside the function/subroutine and call a subroutine passing the array as argument and providing intent(out) to indicate that it is a return value. So it made sense to me that for dynamic array I should be able to allocate the memory outside the subroutine and let the subroutine write to it, and the same time write intent(out) since the array is actually the output of the subroutine.

Comment: @Matthias That's the common strategy, yes, but when you pass a complex type, the complex type is cleared, including any allocated it contains. This is why I strongly discourage the use of intent(out) for complex types. Sooner or later you will forget its existence and it will stab you in the back. We stepped on this too many times.

Comment: @Matthias009 -- what you want to do is disallowed.  With intent(out), the allocation status is lost on entry to the procedure, so you can't allocate the memory outside of the subroutine.  It doesn't have anything to do with being a user-defined (complex) type or not.   See page 240 of "Fortran 95/2003 explained" for a discussion of this -- google will show you this page if you search on "allocatable argument intent out".

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it seems best to me that I just stay with intent(out) and allocate my array inside the function instead. If I have two functions, one taking the output array of the other as input (in C++ func2(func1(parameter));) I conclude I should allocate inside func1 and deallocate after func2.